# How can I kill a terminal command right after I call it without using ctrl + c?

Tags: terminal

I'm on a mac and I'm often run a commands like these:

```
user@host ~/ $ tail -f /some/directory/api-access.log | code -
```

```
user@host ~/ $ php artisan route:list | code -
```

And all those commands do is get the output and opens in visual studio code. But after that command is called it keeps the command open in terminal. After opening the output in visual studio code I'd like for the command to stop. Ideally I'd like a one-liner so that I don't have to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, how can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like `code` is still running and you don't want it to stop. If so, put `&` at the end of the line?

Comment: @Patrick I think the idea is to kill e.g. `tail -f` as soon as `code` has started and read the data from the pipe.

Comment: If so, he shouldn't be using `-f`.

Comment: This is an AB question. You have decided that you need to kill the process, so are asking how to do this. However it is clear that this is not what you are trying to achieve. Fix the question to tell us what you are trying to do (clearly).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor No that seems like that's exactly what I want to do. Open the output in VS code and then kill the process in terminal

Comment: @Xecure yes I know, I just am not sure that is the best thing to do, to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @Patrick @Kusalananda I wouldn't get too caught up in the `tail -f` command. Sometimes terminal will output something large and it's easier for me to view the output in an editor.

Comment: Does `code` exit when you close the file in VS?  If so, just background it and be done with it.  Killing processes is rarely the right solution.  Better question: Does `(x=0; while sleep 1; do printf '%d\n' "$x"; x="$(expr "$x" + 1)"; done) | code -` continue adding lines to your VS window?  If so, does it continue after killing the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the terminal to be avaliable for you immediately, while the editor still runs. Since both the editor and the preceding command are components of a pipeline, you can't just send one or the other to the background. You'll have to background them both.

I assume that `code` is some kind of a GUI-based editor, so it won't inherently occupy the terminal by itself.

```
$ ( tail -f /some/directory/api-access.log | code - ) &
```

or

```
$ ( php artisan route:list | code - ) &
```

Comment: This did the trick!

Comment: You don’t need the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

While I am sure that you have asked an AB quesion. That is you have decided to go for solution A to problem B, and are now asking how to do A. When you should be asking about B.

That said.

```
program &
kill $!
```

If you try this you will regret it. It has many problems (race hazards, does not really solve your problem, but does answer the question).

This may solve your problem.

```
program &
```

As long as the programs ends some time.